# Rounded Edges on Image

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Say I have created a polygon-shaped image by creating a shape in HTML5 canvas and then filling it with an image, e.g. as below:

[image]

Now I want to round the corners on this hexagon.

There is a `lineJoin = "round"` property available but this doesn't seem to work (I believe because the shape is filled and there is no outer line to round).

Does anyone have any idea how to do this with HTML5 canvas or any other means?

Here is the code used to create the image:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
var a = ctx.canvas.width, r = a / 5;

var side = Math.sqrt((4/3) * r * r);


// Draw your image onto the canvas (here I'll just fill the
// surface with red
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Mountain_Bluebird.jpg";

img.onload = function () {
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, a, a);
  
  // Switch the blending mode
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';

  // Draw the hexagon shape to mask the image
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, side/2);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 3*side/2);
  ctx.lineTo(r, 2*side);
  ctx.lineTo(2*r, 3*side/2);
  ctx.lineTo(2*r, side/2);
  ctx.lineTo(r, 0);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
};
```

```html
<canvas width="1000" height="1000" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Draw your lines that create the hexagon a little shorter, so that they end a bit before each corner point, and then draw an [arc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) to create the rounded corner. (Will probably need some calculations to get the positions and angles right.) // Maybe using a CSS clip path or an SVG mask would make this easier. https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: Just curious. :-) Why use a pattern instead of `context.drawImage`?

Comment: @markE I was just using the first thing I came across to geth the job done at first, but you may be right wrt using ```context.drawImage```; http://jsperf.com/drawimage-vs-canvaspattern/16. Not sure I know enough about canvas to make a well informed decision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the order you draw in and then change `globalCompositeOperation` to `'source-in'`.

I made some adjustments because some of the corners in your code were getting clipped off but didn't adjust the image position (I hope that's easy enough to do)

---

**Preview**

You need to adjust the image position by the way like I said

[image]

---

**Snippet**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
var a = ctx.canvas.width, r = a / 5;

var side = Math.sqrt((4/3) * r * r) - 20;


// Draw your image onto the canvas (here I'll just fill the
// surface with red
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Mountain_Bluebird.jpg";

img.onload = function () {
  
  ctx.lineJoin = "round";
  ctx.lineWidth = 50;

  // Draw the hexagon shape to mask the image
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(50, 50 + side/2);
  ctx.lineTo(50, 50 + 3*side/2);
  ctx.lineTo(50 + r, 50 + 2*side);
  ctx.lineTo(50 + 2*r, 50 + 3*side/2);
  ctx.lineTo(50 + 2*r, 50 + side/2);
  ctx.lineTo(50 + r, 50);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
  
  // Switch the blending mode
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, a, a);
  
};
```

```html
<canvas width="1000" height="1000" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: No worries! I forgot to mention that I also added a `ctx.stroke()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way of doing this. The canvas API is pretty low-level, so it doesn't know that you've drawn a shape and want to detect where all the edges are. What you can do, but it would be a bit of a hassle to do is use `bezierCurveTo`. This method takes size arguments and can create curves. Combine that with your lines, and you can create rounded corners.

[bezierCurveTo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp)

You could also add circles at all the corners, with the `arc` method.